# Remove the last digits of a number (not string)

Tags: javascript

How can I remove the last digits of a number (not string) using JavaScript.

Example:

```
   Input : 2121.1124
   Output : 2121.112
```

I google it a lot. But everywhere I found remove string. How can I do it?

This is the code for remove last char of a string.

```
            var str = "stackoverflow";
            str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
            console.log(str);
```

How can I do it for a digit(not string) ?

Comment: youre sure you dont want to round  ?

Comment: convert it to a string than back to a float if you can do it with a string

Comment: But what wrong with strings? Truncating a string will give you exactly what you want.
Why do you need only number operations?

Comment: You are dealing with a float, why the heck are you looking for substring? `Number.prototype.toFixed()` is the right way. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Answer (score 6):

Use `number.toFixed(amountOfDecimals);` to round, where `amountOfDecimals` is 3.

Use `Math.floor( number * Math.pow(10, amountOfDecimals) ) / Math.pow(10, amountOfDecimals);` to avoid rounding. So, for 3 decimal places, that becomes `Math.floor( 2121.1124 * 1000 ) / 1000;`

Not sure which one you need.

**Edited** to reflect h2ooooooo's suggestion below.

Comment: (it should be noted that the `1000` in the last part is the result of `Math.pow(10, amountOfDecimals)`. Every additional zero would add another decimal).

Answer (score 0):

```
output= parseInt(input*1000)/1000
```

## How does it work ?

the parseInt(input*1000) will remove all nums after the third after the decimal.

Answer (score 0):

You can display the decimal numbers using `toFixed()` like the following:

`parseFloat(2121.1124).toFixed(3)` this will return `2121.112`

Comment: `parseFloat()` is rather unnecessary here.

Comment: Yes, but it is good to use parseFloat so this will work even the variable holds string values

Comment: @Vinoth Not if it's already a float. `var foo = String(String(String(String(String('foo')))))` would just be silly.